# compare two different dates in php

Tags: php

I have 2 dates. One is `$monthToCheck  = date('Y-m-01');` and the other one comes from an API and its stored in a variable : `$reqs['end_date']`. My question is : How do i check if the date from the api is bigger than $monthToCheck. With bigger i mean for example 2020 - 01 - 01 is bigger than 2019 - 12 - 01 because the year is higher.

What i tried :

```
     $time = strtotime($reqs['end_date']);
     $monthToCheck  = date('Y-m-01');
     if($time > $monthToCheck) {...}
```

I converted the date from the API to a date using strtotime and then compared it with my $monthToCheck variable.But i have a feeling something isnt right since the results are all "true" eventho that is not always the case.

Comment: `strtotime(date('Y-m-01'));` then you are comparing apples with apples

Comment: So date('Y-m-01'); is also a string ? hmm @RiggsFolly

Comment: @Kevin.a yes^ var_dump it

Comment: oh my bad , i honestly thought it would convert to a date @treyBake

Comment: `(new DateTime('date1')) > (new DateTime('date2'))`

Comment: As you can see in [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), the `date()` function returns the date as a string. When in doubt, check the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your `$monthToCheck` into `strtotime()`:

```
$monthToCheck  = strtotime(date('Y-m-01'));
```

[Example](https://3v4l.org/venDG)

Answer (score 0):

php can compare dates formatted year-mm-dd easily

```
if($monthToCheck > $reqs['end_date']){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Comparing 2 integers is always more reliable than comparing 2 strings representing dates

Comment: interesting comment, do you have an example where my technique is less reliable, i'd like to test this

Comment: It just stands to reason. Specially as some countries like to put there date in non-logical formats like starting in the middle and working out in one direction or another from there. I speak of the way Americans like to write the dates mm/dd/yyyy :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly that you need to have your date in a proper sortable format for this, is rather a given, I think. That this won’t work with just any arbitrary date format, should be clear to everyone. And considering that the question was about comparing the date part only, timestamps might also give you trouble - when you compare two timestamps that are for the same date, but have different times. Which could rather easily happen as well, if the dates to compare are from different source, and time zone settings might not have been taken into account correctly, or anything like that.